# How can I get these static IPv4 routes to work?

Tags: routing, ipv4, linux

I am very new to linux networking and am trying to setup the following topology setup for some VMs on a testbed. 
(Please note, I have to have the VMs setup exactly this way for my testing purposes. I can't cheat and put them on switches. They all need to be on separate nets).

```
Node1     Node2     Node3     Node4
eth[x]<-->eth[x]    eth[x]<-->eth[x]
          eth[y]<-->eth[y]
```

I'm currently trying to get Node4 to talk to Node2 via Node3, but failing miserably. Can someone tell me were I'm going wrong and how to correct it?

Node1's IP:

```
eth2 - 10.1.3.2/24
```

Node2's IPs

```
eth3 - 10.1.1.2/24
eth4 - 10.1.3.3/24
```

Node3's IPs

```
eth1 - 10.1.2.2/24
eth3 - 10.1.1.3/24
```

Node4's IP

```
eth4 - 10.1.2.3/24
```

(Routes, from "ip route")
The route for Node1:

```
10.1.3.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.3.2
```

The route for Node2:

```
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.2 
10.1.3.0/24 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.3.3
```

The route for Node3, after adding a via:

```
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth3  scope link  src 10.1.1.3 
10.1.2.0/24 dev eth1  scope link  src 10.1.2.2 
10.1.3.0/24 via 10.1.1.2 dev eth3
```

The route for Node4:

```
10.1.2.0/24 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.2.3
```

With this setup, Node3 can ping Node2's address at 10.1.3.3, but Node4 cannot ping this address. What do I need to do to enable Node4 to be able to ping 10.1.3.3? Also, how can I get Node4 to be able to communicate all the way to Node1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step one, enable *IP Forwarding* on node2 and node3 (or the nodes will be "hosts" not "routers")

All the nodes need to know what isn't *directly attached*:

### Node1

```
ip route add 10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.3.3
ip route add 10.1.2.0/24 via 10.1.3.3
```

### Node2

```
ip route add 10.1.2.0/24 via 10.1.1.3
```

### Node3

```
ip route add 10.1.3.0/24 via 10.1.1.2
```

### Node4

```
ip route add 10.1.3.0/24 via 10.1.2.2
ip route add 10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.2.2
```

(This would be A LOT easier to see if it were all in one picture.)

Comment: Great insight. I see what you're doing there. However, when I added this to the network, I still can't ping from node4 to node2. On node4, I am doing a "ping 10.1.1.2". I can ping from node4 to both of the interfaces on node3 (10.1.2.2 and 10.1.1.3). Am I missing something?

Comment: Arg! I was missing something. You called it step 1. Yay for reading comprehension. Enabling that after adding the routes made everything better. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Node4 doesn't have routes to the prefixes other than its own. How does Node4 know where to send traffic for Node2's `10.1.3.3` address?

Routing protocols will let routers tell each the routes about which they know, so that each router knows to send traffic for a prefix in a specific direction. You can do this with static routes, but it is not scalable or dynamic.

What the end nodes should have is a default route `0.0.0.0/0` pointing to their single interface.  This falls apart if they have more than one interface. The two middle nodes will need routes to the prefixes to which they don't have direct contact, and this shouldn't be done with default routes.

Imagine a network with many routers where you are trying to keep up with this sort of thing. You can see why routing protocols were created. Static routing has its uses, but trying to completely run a network using is is a recipe for going insane.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to run an entire network this way-- just 4 VMs for testing some things. I agree, static routing all day would not be fun.

Comment: I understand that, but I just wanted to point out that it could quickly become unmanageable if you decide to make this any bigger.

Comment: Oh believe me, I won't. That would be a nightmare. I'm just trying to set up a simple, rudimentary network so I can play with click: http://read.cs.ucla.edu/click

Comment: So, it just boils down to telling each node how to get to the prefixes about which it doesn't know.